# Rule-based color in dataPlotly bar chart in Atlas

Tags: qgis-3, atlas, dataplotly

I have created an Atlas in QGIS 3.10 and have made a bar chart that changes accordingly to the corresponding Atlas feature.

x-axis: area type and y-axis: area in square meters

I also managed to set the color for each bar to correspond to the color of the area type shown in the current atlas map by using an data defined expression for the bar color

`case
  when "artype"=11 then color_rgb(255,85,255)
  when "artype"=12 then color_rgb(197,197,197)
  ...
end`

[image: Atlas feature no. 1]

[image: Atlas feature no. 2]

Now, I wonder if it is possible to

1. change the label sizes (or colors and font types) without using
   HTML-tag like `<b>` and `<i>` e.g.
   `<b style="font-size:120%;">Arealtype</b>`. I've tried `<h1>` and `<p>`
   without any luck.
2. just highlight the largest area type (the highest bar), i.e. showing
   the largest area type in orange color, the rest of the bars in grey.
   I have tried different variants of

   `case
      when attributes(get_feature('Dissolved','areal_u32',maximum("areal_u32",filter:="rn"=@atlas_featurenumber)))['artype']=11
   then color_rgb(255,127,0)
      ...
      else color_rgb(229,229,229) 
    end`

   but always (of course?) ending up with all bars being orange.
3. keep all area types on the x-axis in a predefined order. The
   bar height will be zero for area types not present in the current
   atlas map. This would make it even easier to compare the bar charts
   for each atlas map.

Can all/some of this already be achieved or do I have to wait for QGIS 3.11?